# Install elephant.io without composer

Tags: php

I wanna connect to socket.io server and decided to try use elephant.io library, but i never used the composer, and don't wont to try. Is there a way to install elephant.io without composer (maybe simple copying the library's files)?

Comment: The [github page](https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io) says *For other ways, you can check the release page, or the git clone urls.*

Comment: You should bite the bullet and learn Composer. It's simple, easy, and the modern way of working with PHP packages. There's a reason every modern PHP framework and library uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the releases from 
https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io/releases
extract it, and just require_once the file Client.php for example.